# Issue with display function

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a problem with one of my linked list display function. The function is as below.

I am just calling the function in one of the switch statement. But nothing is getting displayed. Please help me figure out where i am going wrong.

Code:

```
void display ()
{
    data *cur_point;

    cur_point = head;       

    if(cur_point = NULL)
    {
        printf("The list is empty");
    }
    else
    {   
        while(cur_point != NULL)
        {
            printf("Name : %s \n Contact Number : %d \n",cur_point->name,cur_point->telno);
            cur_point = cur_point -> nextp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please compile your program with maximum compiler warning and have a look at the compiler warnings and try to fix them, they can help you find out bugs like these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
if(cur_point = NULL)
```

To:

```
if(cur_point == NULL)
```

Voila! :) (Clarification: You set cur_point to `NULL` in your code instead of checking if it is `NULL`)

Answer (score 3):

If you see something like this it should immediately trigger panic:

```
if(cur_point = NULL)
```

`=` assigns, `==` would check.